# Is there a way to automatically verify identities using geolocation for some users?

Tags: permission-sets, two-factor-authentication

Is there a way to enable **Let Salesforce Authenticator automatically verify identities using geolocation** setting **only for some users** with Permission Set or some other way? I'm trying to enable automatic 2FA approval with the Salesforce Authenticator app using geolocation only for System administrator users.

By default the **Let Salesforce Authenticator automatically verify identities using geolocation** checkbox setting can be enabled only to the entire organization under: Security Controls > Session Settings > Identity Verification
[image]

Comment: Out of the box - no. Please update your question with more information on what you're trying to achieve (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: I'm trying to enable automatic 2FA approval with the Salesforce Authenticator app using geolocation only for System administrator users. @identigral

Comment: Your best option out of the box is to use Authenticator for everyone and [auto-approve based on location + IP](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317978&type=1&mode=1). If that is not acceptable, you can customize the UX via a [Login Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow.htm&type=5). The important caveat is that while you can "engage" Authenticator in Login Flow, you can only do so via TOTP (enter a code..) rather than a push notification + tap. Look at 3rd party [MDM](https://bit.ly/33n6Mqk) products for more finesse.